# Unable to change div color in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

I have written this JavaScript file (using jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[data-action=open]").click(show_category);
    $("[data-action=close]").click(hide_category);
});
function show_category() {
    var $category = $(this).data("target");
    if ($("#"+$category).is(":visible")) {
        hide_category($category);
    } else {
        $("#"+$category).show(250);
    }
    $("[data-action=close][data-target="+$category+"]").attr("data-visible", "1");
}
function hide_category($var) {
    if (typeof $var == 'string') {
        var $category = $var;
        $("[data-action=close][data-target="+$category+"]").attr("data-visible", "0");
    } else {
        var $category = $(this).data("target");
        $(this).attr("data-visible", "0");
    }
    $("#"+$category).hide(250);
}
```

The `div` that I want to make invisible (by changing the colour to transparent) never  changes the colour to transparent. I have tried changing `attr("data-visible", "0")` to `css("color", "transparent")` but that also had no effect. **This only happens when I click on the `a` that has `[data-action=open]`. My HTML is here:**

```
<a class="category_header" data-target="websites" data-action="open" href="#side_nav">Websites</a>
<a href="#side_nav" data-target="websites"  data-action="close" data-visible="0">✕</a>
```

I'm trying to make it so that I can click the same `a` to hide and show, but there's also the option of clicking the `✕`.

Finally, I tried changing it to `css("background", "blue")` just for testing and that worked. Here is relative SCSS:

```
&[data-action="close"] {
    width: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #111;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    color: transparent;
    &[data-visible="1"] {   
        color: $#fafafa;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

**I made a jsFiddle that also doesn't work, using my codes: http://jsfiddle.net/RmeSJ/ The X doesn't disappear until clicked..**

Comment: If I'm correct, `data('anything')` doesn't return a value, try `attr("data-anything")`, sorry if I'm incorrect.

Comment: When I run `var $category = $(this).data("target"); alert($category);` an alert with the correct data appears, so I think it works.

Comment: @Xero The value will return with .data() and it try to cast the value, with .attr() is only a simple string.

Comment: @user2491647 Did you try with opacity? Maybe Help

Comment: @WilfredoP, Please see my jsFiddle

Comment: @user2491647 I got a 404 error in you fiddle

Comment: @WilfredoP Please try again with this link: http://jsfiddle.net/RmeSJ/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to:

```
function hide_category($var) {
    var $category = (typeof $var == 'string') ? $var : $(this).data("target");
    $("#" + $category).hide(250, function() {
        $("[data-action=close][data-target=" + $category + "]").attr("data-visible", "0");
    });
}
```

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/RmeSJ/2/

Comment: Thank you! But why does this function work and not my above function?

Comment: The order of .hide(). You need to hide first and then change the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the element why not use:

```
$("[data-action=close][data-target="+$category+"]").css('display', 'none');
```

or

```
$("[data-action=close][data-target="+$category+"]").hide();
```

Comment: If I hide it, then there's a blank space. My `a` tags are set to `display: inline-block` and so I just want the colour transparent. But, that works if only that was what I'm trying to achieve...

Comment: If you want it invisible, but it still takes up space, try `css('opacity', 0)`?  Or is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: @LLPrudente, Please see my jsFiddle

Comment: Or if you set an external content with size, you can hide the element without  blank space (: